# Shell script: check for file doesn't work if there is a symlinked directory involved?

Tags: shell-script, symlink, macos, test

If I have

```
/mydir/myfile.txt
```

this code echos `file already exists`

```
if [ ! -f "/mydir/myfile.txt" ]; then
    touch "/mydir/myfile.txt"
    echo "created file"
else
    echo "file already exists"
fi
```

but if I instead have

```
/mysecondarydir/myfile.txt
```

and then

```
ln -s /mysecondarydir /mydir
```

so that `/mydir` is a symbolic link rather than a regular directory the code above echos `created file`.

I of course want it to treat both cases the same way. How do I do that?

Comment: can't reproduce - works as desired

Comment: `ln -s /mysecondarydir /mydir` may create `/mydir/mysecondarydir` if `/mydir` resolves to an existing directory

Comment: From man `bash`: _"Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link itself."_ So `-f` should also return true if it's a symlink whose target is a regular file. If it doesn't work for you, you're missing something else. Run `ls -l` on all the relevant directories/files/links to ensure they are what you think they are.

Comment: Is this on a filesystem that treats considers `/mydir` and `/MyDir` to be the same directory (such as on MacOS)?

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes it is MacOS. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @d-b Some of Apple's default filesystems are case-insensitive (but case-preserving), this is the case for HFS+ volumes by default, I believe.

Comment: @d-b what are the **actual** names of the directory and the symlink you're creating?  Do they happen to be the same name except one is mixed case and the other is all lowercase (such as `ln -s Downloads downloads`)?

Comment: @SottoVoce No. I execute a script in ~/recordings/ which looks for a textfile with the same but, except for the extension, in ../texts/ (i.e., ~/texts/). It worked fine until I changed ~/texts from a directory to a symlink pointing somewhere else (on the network).

Comment: please run `ls -ld /mysecondarydir /mydir` and `ls -l /mysecondarydir/ /mydir/ /mydir/myfile.txt` and `readlink -f /mydir/myfile.txt`. Of course, for the directories and files you need. As already stated, given your setup the script should work as expected. If it doesn't, you're probably missing something that would explain why it's not working as expected.

Comment: @d-b please explain what you mean by "pointing to somewhere else (on the network)".  Symbolic links point to filesystem objects (directories or files), not network devices/locations.  Is there a remote filesystem here that's not mentioned in your question?

Comment: @SottoVoce The symlink points at `~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-myname@gmail.com/My device/texts/`. This directory isn't treated as a regular directory in the GUI (but is "normal" when accessing it using the command line). It is a "mirror" of my Google Drive.

Comment: Is unexpanded tilde literally in the target string of the symlink?

Comment: @d-b and how does the `ln -s` command work when both the source and destination of the symlink are on the local MacOS filesystem?  Do you still see the problem described in your question?